# configureCell different between Xcode 6x and 7x

Tags: swift, xcode

I am trying to learn Swift and decided to use "Swift for Dummies" published in 2015. The sample code used in the book is for XCode 6.X but I am using Xcode 7.2.1.

In chapter 4, there is a code for configureCell in MasterViewController.swift but it is not compatible for Xcode 7.X

Dummies has the following:

```
func configureCell(cell: UITableViewCell, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
      let object = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as Event
      cell.textLabel!.text = "latitude: " + object.latitude.description + " longitude: " + object.longitude.description
}
```

Xcode 7.X does not use indexPath and I don't have a clue of how to recode the func.

```
func configureCell(cell: UITableViewCell, withObject object: NSManagedObject) {

/* I mangled the code inside the braces so I decided not to reproduce it here*/   
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

I have recoded the function to the best of my abilities and now Xcode no longer reports an error. Is the following code correct?

```
func configureCell(cell: UITableViewCell, withObject object: NSManagedObject) {

   let objectgt = object as! Event

    cell.textLabel!.text = "latitude: " + objectgt.valueForKey("latitude")!.description + " longitude: " + objectgt.valueForKey("longitude")!.description
   }
```

Comment: There are tons of differences with each version of Swift.  Does Xcode 7 let you set the Swift version. If so, set it to the version used by the book.  Or, get an older Xcode here: https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

Comment: Downloading older version of Xcode is only available for paid accounts. My account is a free one.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to be the bearer of bad news, but I honestly think you should not use such an outdated book. You'll spend a lot of time learning things that no longer work.  As the commenters above mentioned, swift has changed a lot, and so has Xcode.  If you finish the book, you would still be at a great disadvantage compared to those who are using current tools (and the current language).

I recommend you try the "HackingWithSwift" website for a free resource to get you started (40 free example tutorials) at https://www.hackingwithswift.com [or something similar], and then decide how you want to proceed. You should use current tools, and at least Swift 3.1 or you will have difficulties understanding new code.

One last thought: Swift has gotten easier since XCode6 days.  The method calls/parameters are now more consistent and easier to work with. That will help make the learning process smoother and more enjoyable.

Comment: Hacking with Swift (click the above link). You can try it online, and if you like it, you can buy the ebook from there as well. It's not very expensive, and has over 1300 pages. I bought the "Hacking with macOS" book, and am happy with it, which is why I recommended the site. Plus he updates everything for free when the language changes.